# C++: Using a template parameter as a default argument in a template function

Tags: c++, function-templates

Given the snippet of code below:

```
template<int n, double m>
void function(int x=n){
 double y=m;
 int array[n];
 ….
}

void main () {
 function<1+2,2>(8);
}
```

when the function is compiled is x going to be 3 or 8 (as n is just the default parameter)?

Comment: n is just become type when function called. int in your case when you call function(8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's the benefit of that code!!.

The template non-type parameter must be a structural type (can't be double). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter

Hence If the `double` changed to be `int`, the vars would be `x=8`, `n=3` and `m=2`.

Another thing change `void main()` to `int main()`. See [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: it was shown in one of the slides in my course. it's for pure educational purpose, no real utility. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your example `n` is 3 and `x` is 8. The actual parameter value takes precedence over the default one.